# Problem handling enviroment variable when launching terminal from bash script

Tags: bash, sh

The following script gets called with an enviroment variable setted.
I need to launch a terminal and inside that terminal read that variable from another script ( `script.sh` ).

```sh
xfce4-terminal -x sh -c \
"export VAR='${VAR}'
/home/usr/scripts/script.sh"
```

It works but not when `VAR` has single quotes in it.
I also feel like there is a better way to pass enviroment variable to the terminal but I don't know how.

I really appreciate any kind of help and I'm sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

One of the intended features of the environment is that you can add to it, but you never *remove* things from it. Add `VAR` to the current environment, and it will be inherited by `xfce4-terminal` and any process started by that terminal.

```
export VAR
xfce4-terminal -x sh -c /home/usr/scripts/script.sh
```

If you don't want it in the current environment, only in the new terminal's, then use a precommend assignment.

```
VAR="$VAR" xfce4-terminal -x sh -c /home/usr/scripts/script.sh
```

This avoids any fragile dynamic script construction like you are contending with.

---

Since `xfce4-terminal` appears to not fork a new process itself, I would pass the desired value as an argument to `sh`.

```
xfce4-terminal -x sh -c 'VAR="$1" /home/usr/scripts/script.sh' _ "$VAR"
```

The argument to `-c` is still a fixed string rather than one generated by interpolating the value of `$VAR`.

Comment: Thanks for the replay but I've tried it and it doesn't work.
The variable is not readable inside the script.
It can see the variable only when I explicitly execute `export` inside the terminal command.

Comment: Hm, I wonder if `xfce4-terminal` is actually sending a message to some other component to fork a new process.

Comment: you're right! the problem is the terminal. I tried with urxvt and it worked.

Comment: what could I do to use xfce4-terminal?

Comment: My update should work for `xfce4-terminal`, letting `sh` itself set the environment for `script.sh`.